# How to use FakeItEasy to verify FindOneAndUpdateAsync method ran Against faked MongoCollection?

Tags: c#, mongodb, unit-testing, fakeiteasy

I am using the `FakeItEasy` library for unit testing and trying to write a unit test for a mongo update statement and verify that the `FindOneAndUpdateAsync` method was called using `MustHaveHappened()`.

I have created a unit test that will fake the `dbcontext` class, use that to generate a collection, then call the method that will run the update statement against the fake collection. When I run the test in debug mode, it is hitting the `FindOneAndUpdateAsync` method, however the `MustHaveHappened()` result is showing that the method did not run against the faked collection.

Is there a way to use `FakeItEasy` to detect that the `FindOneAndUpdateAsync` method ran when the collection it is being run against is also being faked?

**Error Message from Failed Test**

> Assertion failed for the following call:
>       Any call made to the fake object.
>         where x => (x.Method.Name == "FindOneAndUpdateAsync")
>     Expected to find it once or more but didn't find it among the calls:
>       1: MongoDB.Driver.IMongoCollection`1[ConsoleApp3.Fruit].WithWriteConcern(writeConcern: { w : "majority" })

**Unit Test Using FakeItEasy**

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task TestFruitUpdate()
    {
        IDBContext fakeDbContext = A.Fake<DBContext>();
        var fakeMongoCollection = A.Fake<IMongoCollection<Fruit>>();
        var fruitEntity = new Fruit()
        {
            Id = new MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId(),
            Name = "Apple",
            Price = 2.0,
            Quantity = 3,
        };

        A.CallTo(() => fakeDbContext.GetCollection<Fruit>()).Returns(fakeMongoCollection);
        A.CallTo(fakeDbContext).WithReturnType<IMongoCollection<Fruit>>().Returns(fakeMongoCollection);

        var repository = new FruitRepository(fakeDbContext);

        await repository.UpdateFruitQuantityAsync(fruitEntity);

        A.CallTo(fakeMongoCollection).Where(x => x.Method.Name == "FindOneAndUpdateAsync").MustHaveHappened();
    }
```

**Interface for DBContext**

```
public interface IDBContext
{
    IMongoClient Client { get; }

    IMongoDatabase Database { get; }

    IMongoCollection<TDocument> GetCollection<TDocument>()
        where TDocument : Fruit;
}
```

**Fruit Entity**

```
public class Fruit
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

**Fruit Repository Class**

```
class FruitRepository
{
    private readonly IDBContext _dbContext;

    public FruitRepository(IDBContext dBContext) =>
        _dbContext = dBContext;

    public virtual Task UpdateFruitQuantityAsync(Fruit fruitEntity) =>
        _dbContext.GetCollection<Fruit>()
            .WithWriteConcern(WriteConcern.WMajority)
            .FindOneAndUpdateAsync(
                Builders<Fruit>.Filter.Eq(j => j.Id, fruitEntity.Id),
                Builders<Fruit>.Update.Set(j => j.Quantity, fruitEntity.Quantity)
             );
}
```

Comment: Refactor test to be `async Task`. ie: `public async Task TestFruitUpdate()`

Comment: @Nkosi, I changed it to use Task instead of Void per your comment.

Comment: And what happened when you made the change?

Comment: @Nkosi, it didn't have any affect on the test's result.

Comment: This is a nice question. Even though I've never used Mongo, you included enough context for me to reproduce your problem in a few tens of seconds!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the result of `WithWriteConcern` is not the `fakeMongoCollection`. That's why FakeItEasy didn't see the `FindOneAndUpdateAsync` call, even though you saw that call made on *something* when you were debugging. Sometimes in these confusing cases, it's worthwhile checking the identity (ReferenceEquals) of the objects in the tests.

A new Fake is used because you're configuring `fakeDbContext` twice. Your second call should configure the `fakeMongoCollection` to return itself when it's asked for an `IMongoCollection<Fruit>`:

```
A.CallTo(fakeDbContext).WithReturnType<IMongoCollection<Fruit>>()
    .Returns(fakeMongoCollection);
```

→

```
A.CallTo(fakeMongoCollection).WithReturnType<IMongoCollection<Fruit>>()
     .Returns(fakeMongoCollection);
```